# My discord bot throws error for missing 'event' argument, when trying to read a respond

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

My bot should do the following:
After !number the bot asks for a number between 0 and 1000. Then the user has to write down a number and the bot checks if its the one that was randomly generated.

Currently the command is read and the answer-request is printed, but when i type in a number in discord, the bot throws an error:

```
[ERROR   ] discord.ext.commands.bot: Ignoring exception in command number

    msg = await commands.Bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
TypeError: wait_for() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'
```

(this should be the main problem)

I dont know how to get the 'event' in "the wait_for" part or how i can fix it. I already tried some examples for simular code, without good results.

Maybe someone can help?

This is my Command Class code:

```
# guess_the_number.py
from random import randrange

from discord.ext import commands


class number_guesser(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def number(self, ctx):
        x = randrange(1000)
        print(f"random number: {x}")
        await ctx.send(f"Gib eine Zahl zwischen 0 und 1000 ein @ {ctx.author.name}!")  # f-string

        def check(m):
            return m.content == m.content.isdigit() and m.channel == ctx.channel

        msg = await commands.Bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
        await ctx.send(f"-{msg.content}-")
        if msg == x:
            await ctx.send(f"{msg.content} ist richtig!")
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"{msg.content} ist leider falsch. {x} wär die Lösung!")
```

And this is the main/ bot class:

```
# bot.py

from dotenv import load_dotenv
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from commands.number_guesser import number_guesser

load_dotenv()
is_online = False

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ich bin jetzt online!")
    is_online = True
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break
    print(
        f'{bot.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
    )
    members = '\n - '.join([member.name for member in guild.members])
    print(f'Guild Members:\n - {members}')

    print(len(guild.members))
    await bot.add_cog(number_guesser(bot))


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `commands.Bot` class, when you should be using an instance of the class.

```py
msg = await ctx.bot.wait_for('message', check=check)

# ctx.bot is your instance of the Bot class
# for which you have already connected to Discord
```